# Create a variable equal to the last-non NA value per id of another variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I need your help: I have a dataframe like this subseting in data0 below.

```
data0 <- data.frame(id = c("AH001","AH001","AH002","AH002","AH002","AH002","AH003","AH003","AH003","AH003"),
                    numvisit = c(2,3,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5), 
                    datvisit = c(25/06/2014,24/07/2014,25/06/2014,24/07/2014,25/08/2014,26/09/2014,25/06/2014,24/07/2014,25/08/2014,26/09/2014), 
                    weight = c(51.3,51.4,59.8,59.6,NA,NA,52.2,52.5,NA,NA), 
                    center = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

I would like to create a new variable "poidslast" which would be **the last non-NA** value of the variable "poids" for each Id group. As in what I have here in "dataexpected"

```
dataexpected <- data.frame(id = c("AH001","AH001","AH002","AH002","AH002","AH002","AH003","AH003","AH003","AH003"),
                           numvisit = c(2,3,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5),
                           datvisit = c(25/06/2014,24/07/2014,25/06/2014,24/07/2014,25/08/2014,26/09/2014,25/06/2014,24/07/2014,25/08/2014,26/09/2014), weight =c(51.3,51.4,59.8,59.6,NA,NA,52.2,52.5,NA,NA),
                           center = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                           lastweight = c(NA,51.4,NA,59.6,NA,NA,NA,52.5,NA,NA))
```

I've tried some function such as ave, aggregate, by...but ...
Please help me find a solution!

[image: Screen shot of the dataframe]

Now I would like to transforme my dataframe in wide format and have some things like that : **in this screenshot picture "datawide"==>**

[image: "datawide" format expected]

Comment: which variable is poids? I don't see it in data0

Comment: Oh please! The variable "weight" i would say!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `data.table`, this is one liner:

```
setDT(data0)
data0[data0[!is.na(weight),.I[.N], id]$V1, lastweight := weight]
```

**Explanation:**

1.`data0[!is.na(weight),.I[.N], id]$V1` - This finds index of last non NA values in each group. 
2. Next, we use these index values in `i` position and create a new column `lastweight` by taking corresponding `weight` values at the given indexes.

**More Explanation:**

1.`.I`, `.N` are special variables designed for data.table library. `.I` provides a sequential number for each row. `.N` provides the count of all rows in a group. You can find more information on these in official documentation. 
2. So, here `data0[!is.na(weight),.I[.N], id]$V` I simply groupby `id`, give a number to each row and find the number of last row which is non-na. 
3. Try to do this in steps and you'll understand it better.

**Second Answer:**

This results in the wide shape you want, but doesn't quite match with your output. You should check your output once again and let me know.

```
data0[, rid := seq_len(.N), id]

data1 <- dcast(data0, id + center + lastweight ~ rid, value.var = c('datvisit','weight'))
data1 <- data1[!is.na(datvisit_1)]

print(data1)

      id center lastweight  datvisit_1  datvisit_2  datvisit_3  datvisit_4 weight_1 weight_2 weight_3 weight_4
1: AH001      1       51.4          NA 0.001702369          NA          NA       NA     51.4       NA       NA
2: AH001      1         NA 0.002068851          NA          NA          NA     51.3       NA       NA       NA
3: AH002      1       59.6          NA 0.001702369          NA          NA       NA     59.6       NA       NA
4: AH002      1         NA 0.002068851          NA 0.001551639 0.001434404     59.8       NA       NA       NA
5: AH003      1       52.5          NA 0.001702369          NA          NA       NA     52.5       NA       NA
6: AH003      1         NA 0.002068851          NA 0.001551639 0.001434404     52.2       NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: Impressive! I've try this code and it miraculously work. But i understand nothing. I've just apply it stupidly. Please can you give more explanation! Because I've to apply it in annothers cases so...

Comment: I've also noticed that the new variable created is not added to the nomber of variable of the dataframe in my environment; no problem with that,?? Thanks!

Comment: @DjamiouDossa added more explanation.

Comment: Thanks you for your explanation! Now i've transformed my dataframe in a wide format with  `reshape` and i would like to keep the non NA values of "lastweiht" variable created for each id in the wide format frame. I don't want to develop this variable in wide format dataframe. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @DjamiouDossa can you show me how would the output look like?

Comment: I've just explained it by editing my last question with a picture

Comment: @DjamiouDossa I've added the second answer. Please check and let me know.

Comment: I was offline a few time. Thank you for your answers. I was stuck on these manipulations since last week.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fill` from `tidyr`/`tidyverse`. For whichever column you give it, it fills in the most recent non-`NA` value above (for `.direction = "down"`) or below (for `.direction = "up"`). It works within a grouped dataframe.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data0 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    fill(weight, .direction = "down")
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>    id    numvisit datvisit weight center
#>    <fct>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 AH001       2.  0.00207   51.3     1.
#>  2 AH001       3.  0.00170   51.4     1.
#>  3 AH002       2.  0.00207   59.8     1.
#>  4 AH002       3.  0.00170   59.6     1.
#>  5 AH002       4.  0.00155   59.6     1.
#>  6 AH002       5.  0.00143   59.6     1.
#>  7 AH003       2.  0.00207   52.2     1.
#>  8 AH003       3.  0.00170   52.5     1.
#>  9 AH003       4.  0.00155   52.5     1.
#> 10 AH003       5.  0.00143   52.5     1.
```

Created on 2018-04-30 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).